# Calling a variable from a function in a different JS file

Tags: javascript, html, function, google-chrome-extension, popup

I am working on a chrome extension and I am stuck.  I am not sure if this is even possible but this is what I need to have done.  Basically the user click on the chrome extension and panel opens up (popup.html).  The user is shown a list of images from the web and the user can select the ones they want to edit.  popup.html loads popup.js.   popup.js contains functions and inside those functions are some variable.  Now there is a button in popup.html that takes you to another panel called filters.html.  This is where editing goes.  I am trying to pass the selected images from popup.html to filters.html and I am trying to call that array of images that was gathered in popup.js when popup.html loaded but its null.  What is wrong is this even possible?  When a new html page opens up does that mean it loses track of what happened in the last html page and therefore it loses also track of whatever .js files ran in that same page?

Comment: Have a look at the messaging API at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging 
That way you can send messages between different pages and even different extensions. That should be sufficient for sharing information about what has been selected.

Comment: You wrote: When a new html page opens up does that mean it loses track of waht happened in the last html page and therefore it loses also track of whatever js files ran in that same page?  
of course its like you open another program, if your webpage link target is self all is gone if you choose another target you can reach the opener Dom with window.opener.

normally you can do all the stuff in one page popup and filters and hide the interface of popup and show filters.

you can also use cookies

Comment: @ThorstenArtner'Austria'  how do I go about hiding one interface and displaying the other one with the push of a button and having these two interfaces in one .html page?

Comment: whats the problem you can put the interface of filters html in one div with display:none and popup also in one div if you want the divs moveable to go big or small like tools you have to program that with javascript if you click abutton you can hide the div of popup and show filters.

Answer (score 0):

A new and better way is to use [chrome extension storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). You can store the data from one page and u can read it in other page as data will be stored in chrome itself. Hope it helps